# Use event arguments with other arguments?

Tags: javascript, function, events, arguments

Here's what I want to do:

```
function someEvent(e) {
}

onxxxx="someEvent()"
```

and turn that into:

```
function someEvent(e, arg1, arg2) {
}

onxxxx="someEvent(???)"
```

So basically, I want to pass other arguments including the default `event` one, but I'm not sure quite how to

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417121/is-there-any-way-of-passing-additional-data-via-custom-events

Comment: Why do you need to pass params to your event's callback ?

Comment: @WillP. In essence yes, but no because I need to use the HTML attribute for the event, not addEventListener

Comment: @htatche So that I don't need to write one function for many slightly different pieces of code

Comment: How are you binding the event?

Comment: You could have function1, function2, function3, functionX, each one calling `someEvent()` with a different set of arguments, and then call one of those functions from onxxx. But I still don't see a real need for it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the event object as an argument:

```
onxxxx="someEvent(event, arg1, arg2);"
```

`event` must be literal `event` here.

Within the eventhandler function you find them like so:

```
function someEvent(e, a, b) {
    // e === event object
    // a === arg1
    // b === arg2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use anonymous functions:

```
var arg1 = "12345 - test", arg2 = 42;

onxxxxx = function(e) {
    someEvent.call(this, e, arg1, arg2);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to know how to do it straight from HTML attributes, Teemu's answer works

Comment: @leaf68 OK. I didn't understand that was what you wanted.