# TypeError: e is null

Tags: javascript, events, keyup

I am using on keyup event but getting

> type error: e is null .

I am using the event like

`onkeyup="GetDashboardcatAjax('<?=$curpage?>',this.id)"` .

What is the problem ?

Comment: Please check $curpage has proper value also, if short_open_tag is allowed in your PHP setting.

Comment: yes it has proper value

Comment: A [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21946909/1169519)?

Comment: The code you've shared does not even have any `e` variable.

Comment: show us the GetDashboardcatAjax function.

Answer (score -1):

I'd try with `onkeyup="GetDashboardcatAjax(event, '<?=$curpage?>', this.id)"`

Comment: How do you know how his function `GetDashboardcatAjax` looks like?

Comment: Even when i used the event also it is showing that error

Comment: Just please upload that function. We won't be able to help you without that.