# event.initEvent vs event.initCustomEvent

Tags: javascript, custom-events

I was working on a task related to `Custom Events` and was wondering, is there a difference between these methods *apart from extra argument for `event data`*

[MDN - The old-fashioned way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#The_old-fashioned_way) uses `event.initEvent` but the polyfill on [MDN - Cutom Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Polyfill) uses `event.initCustomEvent` to initialize event.

I have referred [Passing additional arguments in custom Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417121/is-there-any-way-of-passing-additional-data-via-custom-events), but we can even use `event.details` to set `event data`.

[JSFiddle - Event data with initEvent](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0v0ry1wx/)

So the question is, *Is there any benefit of using specific one of them?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the DOM spec:

> The [`initCustomEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable, detail)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-customevent-initcustomevent) method
>   must, when invoked, run these steps:
>
> 1. If [context object](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-customevent-detail)'s [dispatch flag](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-customevent-detail) is set, terminate these steps.
> 2. [Initialize](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-customevent-detail) the [context object](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-customevent-detail) with *type*, *bubbles*, and *cancelable*.
> 3. Set [context object](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-customevent-detail)'s [`detail`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-customevent-detail) attribute to *detail*.

> The [`initEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-event-initevent) method, when invoked,
>   must run these steps:
>
> 1. If [context object](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-customevent-detail)'s [dispatch flag](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-customevent-detail) is set, terminate these steps.
> 2. [Initialize](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-customevent-detail) the [context object](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-customevent-detail) with *type*, *bubbles*, and *cancelable*.
>
> Note: As [events](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event) have constructors [initEvent()](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-event-initevent) is
>   superfluous. However, it has to be supported for legacy content.

So, apart from the `detail` argument, they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

event.initEvent This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent)

Comment: But it's still there, both in [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-event-initevent) and [WHATWG](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-initevent) specs.